# React chat application text is to long bug issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a chat application with React. İf user text to much like more than 100 letter i cant see all message is going right how can i fix that issue ? You can see in the image.

[image]

```js
{Object.keys(messages).map((keyName) => (
    messages[keyName].isOut 
        ? <div>
            <div className="sender1">
                {messages[keyName].content.text}
                <span className="timestamp1" > {messages[keyName].date}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        : <div>
            <p className="receiver1" >
                {messages[keyName].content.text}
                <span className="timestamp1" > {messages[keyName].date}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
))}
```

```css
.sender1{
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #dcf8c6;
}

.receiver1{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried adding `overflow: visible` in your CSS?

Comment: Also, maybe you should add a `max-width` so that the sender and receiver "boxes" can expand up to a given point

Comment: Try using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` on `.sender1` and `.receiver1`.

Comment: overflow-wrap not working :( its look like the same, i give max-width also didnt work,

Comment: Well, you have a bit of overlapping rules in your CSS; have a look a this snippet and see if it fits your need: https://jsfiddle.net/rq1o85b0/ (CSS could be further optimized by grouping the common attributes between "sender" and "receiver", e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/rq1o85b0/1/)

Comment: I solve this  word-break:break-all; like that

Answer (score 0):

I solve this  word-break:break-all; its working fine right now

Answer (score 0):

you can use the max-width.
I mean:

```
.sender1{
  max-width:300px //example
  word-break: break-all;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #dcf8c6;
}

.receiver1{
  max-width:300px; //example
  word-break: break-all;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
  position: relative;
}
```

and maybe for receiver1, you should for text-align: left.